# Can't assign C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Context: Need to set verts in TestTextures3SpriteObj s1 to the verts1 array. Gives me an error "expression must be modifiable lvalue". After its copied the vertices will be sent to the GPU as buffer data with OpenGL and GLUT.

Only relevant excerpts of code included

```
#pragma once
    class TestTextures3SpriteObj
    {
    public:
        int spriteid;
        int vao;
        int texid;
        float verts[];
    };
    
    const float verts1[] = { 0.5 ,0.5, 0.0, 0.9, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                            0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                            -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                            -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    
    TestTextures3SpriteObj s1;
    
    s1.verts = verts1;
```

Comment: No you can't assign a c-array but you can a c++ array. std::array<> is assignable.

Comment: `float verts[];` is not legal `c++`

Comment: Warning: `float verts[];` looks to be a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). Non Standard in C++.

Comment: float verts[] compiles fine for me. also std::array requires a size to declare it and I'm not sure the size of the array until runtime so I can't declare a size for it before hand as the object might have an array of 4 vertices or more or less vertices. Shouldn't be a vector though because it won't change after its set, only set once

Comment: You may need to turn on more warnings so your compiler notifies you of such things.

Comment: Use constructor to declare size of array or you can resize there.

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean it's a good idea. Standard C++ requires arrays to have compile-time constant sizes. There are a variety of reasons to stay away from non-standard variable length array extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not accessing the variable ...

if you want access individual element, use index

```
s1.verts1[0]
```

If you want to copy use `std::copy`

```
std::copy(verts1, verts1 + 36, s1.verts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class TestTextures3SpriteObj
    {
    public:
        int spriteid;
        int vao;
        int texid;
        float verts[36]; //assign the size to the array
    };
    
    const float verts1[] = { 0.5 ,0.5, 0.0, 0.9, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                            0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                            -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                            -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
int main()
{
    TestTextures3SpriteObj s1;
    int len=sizeof(verts1)/sizeof(verts1[0]);
    //copies the entire array to the object with member verts
    std::copy(verts1, verts1 + 36, s1.verts);
    //printing the values in the s1 object
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        cout<<s1.verts[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Assign a size to the array in the class and then later perform the std::copy to copy the values in the verts array.